# Android Quickblox Video chat error

Tags: android, audio, video, chat, quickblox

I am developing a video chat application for android using Quickblox library. But I am getting some errors while maintaining video chat session. When user gets logged in as receiver (second user) then app gets crashes after some time giving folowing log output.

```
 01-28 18:23:20.149: W/System.err(15082):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
01-28 18:23:20.149: W/System.err(15082):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
01-28 18:23:20.149: W/System.err(15082):    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:98)
01-28 18:23:20.149: W/System.err(15082):    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
01-28 18:23:20.149: W/System.err(15082):    at com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.senders.TcpPacketsSender$TcpVideoAudioSenderRunnable.run(TcpPacketsSender.java:98)
01-28 18:23:20.149: W/System.err(15082):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
01-28 18:23:20.149: W/System.err(15082):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-28 18:23:20.149: W/System.err(15082):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-28 18:23:20.149: W/System.err(15082):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-28 18:23:20.149: W/System.err(15082):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-28 18:23:20.149: W/System.err(15082):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-28 18:23:20.159: W/System.err(15082): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
01-28 18:23:20.159: W/System.err(15082):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
01-28 18:23:20.159: W/System.err(15082):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:146)
01-28 18:23:20.159: W/System.err(15082):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
01-28 18:23:20.159: W/System.err(15082):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:463)
01-28 18:23:20.159: W/System.err(15082):    ... 12 more
01-28 18:23:20.199: W/AudioTrack(15082): obtainBuffer() track 0x7e5788 disabled, restarting
01-28 18:23:20.219: W/ilbc-codec(15082): Ignore last 0 bytes
01-28 18:23:20.349: W/System.err(15082): java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:496)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:465)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:507)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:269)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:98)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.senders.TcpPacketsSender$TcpVideoAudioSenderRunnable.run(TcpPacketsSender.java:98)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-28 18:23:20.359: W/System.err(15082): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe)
01-28 18:23:20.369: W/System.err(15082):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
01-28 18:23:20.369: W/System.err(15082):    at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:146)
01-28 18:23:20.369: W/System.err(15082):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:177)
01-28 18:23:20.369: W/System.err(15082):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:463)
01-28 18:23:20.379: W/System.err(15082):    ... 12 more
```

sometimes it gives AdioRecord error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
```

Anyone have any idea about this or have any other library for chat application integration ?
Thanks

EDIT
Here are some more errors,

```
01-29 16:38:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6775): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3039
01-29 16:38:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6775): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
01-29 16:38:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6775):     at com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.AudioRecorder$AudioRecorderRunnable.run(AudioRecorder.java:123)
01-29 16:38:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6775):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-29 16:38:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6775): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load ilbc-codec: findLibrary returned null
01-29 16:38:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6775):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
01-29 16:38:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6775):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
01-29 16:38:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6775):     at com.googlecode.androidilbc.Codec.<init>(Codec.java:16)
01-29 16:38:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6775):     at com.googlecode.androidilbc.Codec.<clinit>(Codec.java:5)
01-29 16:38:58.831: E/AndroidRuntime(6775):     ... 2 more


01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rechargedoctor.android.app/com.quickblox.videochatsample.ui.ActivityVideoChat}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1959)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1984)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1150)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:534)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.AudioRecorder$AudioRecorderRunnable.initRecorder(AudioRecorder.java:97)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.AudioRecorder$AudioRecorderRunnable.<init>(AudioRecorder.java:75)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.AudioRecorder.startAudioRecorder(AudioRecorder.java:31)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at com.quickblox.module.videochat.core.service.QBVideoChatService.startVideoChat(QBVideoChatService.java:93)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at com.quickblox.videochatsample.ui.ActivityVideoChat.initViews(ActivityVideoChat.java:69)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at com.quickblox.videochatsample.ui.ActivityVideoChat.onCreate(ActivityVideoChat.java:40)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1923)
01-29 11:01:15.772: E/AndroidRuntime(18705):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

just copy the libs/armeabi/libilbc-codec file from the Sample-VideoChat-android project to your new project. everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check, if you copied native library to your project. Than, if you get other errors, try not copy sources of examples into your project, but try to load and run sources of video chat samples, which you can find here https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-android

Comment: I am getting same errors when I try to run sample code also. Is it working fine on your end ? On my side I get bad audio quality.Also video chat gets force closed at various points giving above errors.